# Connection to MV in Osx Fiware Lab

Tags: fiware

I have a problem connecting to my MV Orion in OSX. I performed the following steps:

1. I've created my Keypar and download this
2. I created my security group (port 33, 3306).
3. I created my MV Orion
4. I deployed my MV and associated to Allocated Ip.
5. I open my terminal in my computer (OS X) to try connect to the VM and in the first place have created my key with the following instructions:

   ```
   $ Chmod 600 private.pem
   $ Ssh-keygen -f-and private.pem >> publickey.pub
   Publickey.pub $ cat >> ~ / .ssh / id_rsa.pub
   ```

and when I try to connect:

```
$ Ssh -i my_keypair.pem root@10.0.176.30;
```

the terminal tells me the next sentence:

> `$ Ssh: connect to host 130.206.114.31 port 22`: Network is unreachable.

You know, that may be my problem ?, in the security group have open ports `22` and 3306

Comment: Are the IPs shown in the question right? I mean: you seem to try connecting to an ip in a 10.255.255.255 network (private), and you show an error corresponding to the 130.206.114.31 IP (¿public?). @flopez should be able to help you with this.

Comment: My IP Public in the region Spain 2 is 30.206.114.31 but i don't connect this MV. I don't know the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the problems remains, but keep in mind that in order to access to a virtual machine using the ssh you need to have open the 22 port in your security group. It seems, following your description that it is not the case.